# Include dependency dependencies in the project

Tags: java, gradle

Im new with Gradle and I'm trying to include a java project that I will call project "A" that have some dependencies marked as API (Im using the java-library plugin in the A project) thats includes some modules of the project "A" and dependencies downloaded from maven repositories, and I want include it in the project "B". To do this I'm using the maven publish plugin to publish the project "A" and include as a dependency in the project "B". The result is that in the project "B" only the project "A" sources are included. But when I see the Gradle window It recognizes the dependencies of the project "A" but doesn't includes their classpath.

This is the build.gradle of the project "B":

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "com.github.ynverxe"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenLocal {
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            ignoreGradleMetadataRedirection()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.github.ynverxe.xenov:api:0.0.1")
}
```

Edit: Here are the source code of the project "A": https://github.com/Ynverxe/xenov/tree/dev

Comment: The description is confusing. Project A is an application that references project B as a library?

Comment: @aled No, the project B references the project A. Maybe I explained myself wrong, the project B references the project A as a library, but only the sources of the project A results included but no their dependencies. I want to include all of the project A (sources and dependencies) into the project B.

Comment: If project B is a library then it is not expected for it to include other libraries. And A is not even a library. How do you plan to use B exactly?

Comment: You have not understood me correctly, B IS NOT A LIBRARY, the library is project A.

Comment: Then why are you using the `java-library` plugin on project B? That plugin is used to build Java libraries.

Comment: Project A is a dependency of project B. What I'm looking for is that both the source code of project A and the same libraries of project A are implemented within project B, without having to specify each library that contains project A separately . The result I'm getting is that when I import project A into project B, only the classes from project A are included, but the classes from the libraries that project A uses are not included in project B for some reason.

Comment: @aled The java-library thing was my mistake. I just tried removing the 'java-library' plugin and using "implementation" instead of api to define project A as a dependency. the behavior is the same as before.

Comment: Please update the question with the current configuration, to avoid further confusions.